# Location of the database using Web SQL

Tags: local-storage, web-sql

I am developing an android application using *phoneGap* and finished my UI interfaces.

The problem now is the database. As I am new to this feauture, I don't know where will the database will be stored when we use WebSQL and when we use localStorage attribute

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking (and the 'jquery' tag is irrelevant).

Comment: WebSQL, while supported on most browsers, has been discontinued. A similar API is IndexedDB. Neither of these is directly related to DOM storage ( localStorage , sessionStorage ), and none of these client-side storage options requires "knowing" where the db is (you just provide a name/key, and the browser handles actually storing the data). Are you asking about how to access server-side db from javascript? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to know abt the location where the database is stored so that i could know what and all data is stored

Comment: Where _what_ database is stored? How do you know there is a database if you don't know where it is? How are you currently accessing this database? Do you mean you want to know what data exists in localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFS(){
         window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1, success, fail); 
}

function success( fileSystem ) {
        window.FS = fileSystem;
        console.log(fileSystem.root.toURL());
}
```

**fileSystem.root.toURL()** will give your database path

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the current contents of the `localStorage` object, you can use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
```

this will output a JSON string version of the `localStorage` object to the browser's JS console, which you can access in Firefox using Firebug or in Chrome using Developer Tools.